# need a MYSQL query

Tags: mysql

I am new to mysql,
I have a table `grand_score_master` its data is shown in this image

[image]

I need a query such that, I will pass a user_id say **CBS_00002** and it will return me the rows where the **grand_level** is highest for different packages.

e.g.

[image]

Please help me with this.

Comment: SELECT  DISTINCT package_id, user_id, max(grand_level) FROM `grand_score_master` WHERE user_id='CBS_00002', but it give only 1 row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current query is missing two things.  First, you should be using `GROUP BY`, because you want to find the maximum grand level for each package group, not from the entire table.  Second, you should use a subquery to find the maximum levels, and then use this to restrict the records which you want appearing in your result set.

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM grand_score_master t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT package_id, MAX(grand_level) AS max_grand_level
    FROM grand_score_master
    GROUP BY package_id
) t2
    ON t1.package_id  = t2.package_id AND
       t1.grand_level = t2.max_grand_level
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have started learning Mysql just few days ago and it helps.